# Powershell: Different output while using pipeline and object

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
get-service| get-member #gives output.
```

While

```
$a= get-service 
get-member $a # generates error 
"get-member : No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-member $a
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand"
```

Why so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get-service| get-member` sends each service object, one at a time, to the Get-Member cmdlet, Each object is bound to the InputObject parameter (ByValue) and is processed accordingly.

When you do `get-member $a` you are passing $a to the first position parameter which is the Name parameter, not to the InputObject parameter. In order to get the members of $a (the collection itself):

```
Get-Member -InputObject $a
```

Comment: Thanks shay.
As you mention $a would return the collection of object. How can I get type of individual object and not the collection when using with Get-Member??

Comment: Pipe it to the Get-Member cmdlet

Comment: By the way, $a[0].GetType().FullName would get you the type name of the first object in the collection

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt reply.